# What is Cyanogenmod KANGs?

Tags: cyanogenmod

What is Cyanogenmod KANGs? I have read about compiling the most up-to-date source code as a "KANGs" but I can't find out anywhere what it refers to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CyanogenMod developers coined the term "kang" originally.  It goes back to the beginnings of Android development.  It used to mean having one's development work taken, manipulated, rebranded, and re-released by someone else with no credit to the original developer.

Later this term morphed into having a less malicious meaning, and stands for the process of creating a code based of someone else's code or reapplying code that someone else created into your own code.  A "KANG" therefore is a derivative work, based on the original with some modifications. It usually means an unauthorized version of a custom ROM.